# How to apply clipping to trainable variables in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to know how to apply clipping to a trainable variable in TensorFlow.

I have a variable z that I am training

```
z = tf.get_variable(...)
```

Then I want to optimize it but I want to keep it in the range [-1,1]. Right now, I'm doing the clipping as shown below:

```
train_step = optimizer.minizmize(loss, var_list=[z])
z = tf.clip_by_value(z, -1, 1)
```

But I have the feeling that the clipping is not being performed. How should it be done?

Comment: That is a bit complicated, because each different optimizer decides differently which value to assign to each variable, so in principle you would have to make your own optimizer (e.g. subclass an existing one) to tweak the behavior as you need. However, is it indispensable that your variable has a value between -1 and 1? Maybe you can train the variable normally and then just use the clipped value (with `tf.clip_by_value`, `tf.tanh` or whatever) wherever you use it in your model...

Comment: That would be a solution. But the problem is that the trainable variable represents an uniform random variable between -1 and 1...Thats why I need to keep it bounded. I will try to find an easier solution, otherwise I will implement my own optimized as you proposed. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt at clipping does not work because `tf.clip_by_value` just returns a new tensor that will hold the clipped value of the variable, however the variable itself will not be affected. I.e. after your code snippet the *Python variable* `z` does not point to the originally created *Tensorflow variable* anymore.

If you want to do this manually you should use `tf.assign` to actually assign the clipped value to the variable. However, the most convenient way is likely to use the `constraint` parameter of `get_variable`. Please check [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable). Something like this should work:

```
z = tf.get_variable(..., constraint=lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, -1., 1.)
```

This should apply the function passed to `constraint` after each `minimize` call.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What happens in the case I have to use clip_by_norm?  Im guessing it is not possible to use the constraint parameter since it is applied in each dimension, right?

Comment: The constraint function will take the full variable as input. Thus `clip_by_norm` should work as expected, i.e. it will normalize the variable via its (overall) L2 norm. If you want do something fancier such as normalizing each row separately, you would probably have to write your own function for that (that could still be passed into `constraint`).